# How to call a contract function with multiple arguments?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am trying to call a function of my Solidity contract that takes in 3 arguments.
Here's what my contract function looks like.

```
function test(string memory a, string memory b, string memory c) public{
 // Does something here (alters the data in the contract)
}
```

I am now trying to use web3 version 1.2.1 to send a transaction to this function but I'm encountering errors.

```
instance = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(abi), address);
instance.methods.test("hello_a","hello_b","hello_c").sendTransaction({from:account});
```

The code is in an async() block and all the arguments passed are correct. However I get an error saying sendTransaction is not a function of test.

What am I missing out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `send` instead of `sendTransaction`

```
instance.methods.test("hello_a","hello_b","hello_c").send({from:account});
```

You can read more about available methods [there](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html)